# How to prove Rank(A+B)$\ge$max{Rank(A),Rank(B)} for positive semi-definite A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-rank, positive-semidefinite

How to prove $\text{Rank}(A+B)\ge\max(\text{Rank}(A),\text{Rank}(B))$ if $A\in S_+^n$ and $B\in S_+^n$ (i.e. $A$ and $B$ are both $n\times n$ symmetry positive semi-positive matrices)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since $A+B$ is symmetric, it is orthogonally diagonalizable.$\newcommand{\rank}{\operatorname{rank}}$

If $v_1,..,v_k$ is a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda=0$, then, since $A+B$ is diagonalizable, you have $\rank(A+B)=n-k$.

Now, use 
$$v_j^T (A+B) v_j=0$$
and the fact that $A,B$ are positive semi-definite, to deduce that $$v_j^TAv_j=v_j^TBv_j=0$$

Comment: Thank you! I roughly get it that key proof is to show $v_1,v_2,...,v_n$ is also a subspace of $A$'s($B$'s) eigenspace  corresponding to $\lambda=0$. However I am still confused how to achieve it, specifically, how to show $x^TAx=0$ equivalent to $Ax=0$?

Comment: I eventually worked it out! I will complete the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v_1,v_2,...v_k$ forms a basis for $nullspace$ of $A+B$(i.e. eigenspace corresponding to eigenvalue $0$), now we have $Rank(A+B)=n-k$ and  $v_i^T(A+B)v_i=0$ for i=1,2,3,...k.

Due to the fact that $A$ and $B$ are positive semi-definite matrices, we have:

$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space v_i^TAv_i=0$ and $v_i^TBv_i=0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$
 Then let $A=A^{1/2}A^{1/2}$, due to $A^{1/2}$ is also positive semi-definite we can get

$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space v_i^TA^{1/2}A^{1/2}v_i=(A^{1/2}v_i)^TA^{1/2}v_i=0$

Now I achieve a key intermediate result: $A^{1/2}v_i=0$. And left multiplying $A^{1/2}$ on both sides to get

$\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space Av_i=0$

Now,we can say $v_1,v_2,...v_k$ spans a k-dimension subspace belonging to $A$'s $nullspace$. So we have $k{\le}n-Rank(A)\space i.e. Rank(A){\le}n-k=Rank(A+B)$.

Similarly, we can get $Rank(B){\le}Rank(A+B)$.

Comment: In fact this question comes from proving $Rank(X), {\space}X{\in}S_+^n$ is a quasi-concave function. From [Convex Optimization Boyd & Vandenberghe](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) Example 3.36 at page 98

Comment: To show that $v^TAv=0 \Rightarrow Av=0$ you can also orthogonally diagonalize $A$. This reduces the problem to the case where $A$ is diagonal, which is trivial.

Comment: I tried to diagonalize $A=Q{\Lambda}Q^T$, and $v^TAv=(Q^Tv)^T{\Lambda}Q^Tv=0$, while it cannot show $Q^Tv=0$. So what is the concrete trick?

Comment: Let $$y=Q^Tv=\begin{bmatrix} y_1 \\y_2\\...\\y_n \end{bmatrix} .$$ Then $$y^T\Lambda y=\lambda_1y_1^2+...+\lambda_ny_n^2$$ You need to show that if this is zero, then $$\lambda_1y_1+...+\lambda_ny_n=0$$ which follows from positive semidefiniteness.

Comment: Thank for your patience! I get it.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

The main  statement is 
$$\operatorname{Image}(A+B) = \operatorname{Image}A + \operatorname{Image} B$$
from which the inequality
$$\operatorname{rank} (A+B) \ge \max (\operatorname{rank} A, \operatorname{rank} B)$$ readily follows.

To see the first inequality, notice that for $A$ positive semi-définite we have 
$$(\operatorname{Image} A) ^{\perp} = \{x \ | \ \langle A x, x \rangle = 0 \}$$ and so 
$$(\operatorname{Image} (A+ B) )^{\perp} = (\operatorname{Image} A) ^{\perp}  \cap (\operatorname{Image} B) ^{\perp} $$